# Bootstrap row height changes if I have an Icon in the row

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, icons

I want to have all three rows of my table to have the same height. But the row with the icon in it is always taller.

Is there some magic css setting which will allow me to automatically have all of the rows of the table have a constant height whether I have added an icon to it or not?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
<style>
#my_div {
    line-height: 0.3;
}
.my_icon {
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>


<div class="container-fluid bg-info" id="my_div">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="table-primary row">
        <td class="col-sm-2">No  Icon in this row.  </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-primary row">
        <td class="col-sm-2">Icon Row:
             <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="css-class my_icon"><path d="M15 3h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2h-4"/><polyline points="10 17 15 12 10 7"/><line x1="15" y1="12" x2="3" y2="12"/></svg>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-primary row">
        <td class="col-sm-2">No  Icon in this row.  </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
#my_div {
  line-height: 0.3;
}

.my_icon {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid bg-info" id="my_div">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="table-primary row">
        <td class="col-sm-2">No Icon in this row. </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-primary row">
        <td class="col-sm-2">Icon Row:
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="css-class my_icon"><path d="M15 3h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2h-4"/><polyline points="10 17 15 12 10 7"/><line x1="15" y1="12" x2="3" y2="12"/></svg>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-primary row">
        <td class="col-sm-2">No Icon in this row. </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no magic unfortunattely, you can do this by setting a large height on tds enough to hold your image, or by js, on window load check for the height of the td's and set the height of all of them to the heighest number. btw why are you using bootstrap css for grid on a table?

Comment: Is the text length in the `<td>` static? Or is the text length unknown (short and long lines of text)?

Comment: Thank you for the comment about "bootstrap css for grid on a table". Turns out that everything was happy if I just got rid of the table stuff and just went with grid.

Answer (score 0):

Change your css to this...

```
        .my_icon {
            width: 1em;
            height: 1em;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        tr{
            height: 30px;
        }
        td{
            padding: 0px 10px !important;
        }
```

Modify as desired... works perfectly for me

[image]

Comment: i believe he is looking for a dynamic solution, not having to adjust each time

Comment: He asked for "have all of the rows of the table have a constant height "   That's what he has now.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to have all three rows of my table to have the same height

There's no CSS rule to magically set all row heights to match the tallest row.

But it's simple to accomplish that with some JavaScript:

```js
// set all row heights to match the tallest row

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function() {

  // get all row elements
  const trs = [...document.querySelectorAll('#my_div .row')];

  // determine max height of rows
  const maxRowHeight = trs.reduce((max, tr) => {
    return Math.max(max, tr.offsetHeight);
  }, 0);

  // set height of all rows
  trs.forEach(tr => {
    tr.style.height = maxRowHeight + 'px';
  });

}
```

```css
/* CSS from question (unchanged) */
#my_div {
  line-height: 0.3;
}

.my_icon {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML from question (unchanged) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body class="p-2">
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Resize Rows</button>

  <div class="container-fluid bg-info mt-2" id="my_div">
    <table class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr class="table-primary row">
          <td class="col-sm-2=4">No Icon in this row. </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-primary row">
          <td class="col-sm-4">Icon Row:
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="css-class my_icon"><path d="M15 3h4a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v14a2 2 0 0 1-2 2h-4"/><polyline points="10 17 15 12 10 7"/><line x1="15" y1="12" x2="3" y2="12"/></svg>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-primary row">
          <td class="col-sm-4">No Icon in this row. </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```